# ISP using CGN.. How to port forward ipv6

Tags: networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding, ipv6

I finally came to a conclusion that my ISP is using carrier grade NAT.

I recently was able to encapsulate my IPv4 to IPv6 using tunnel broker. It was working very fine without any issue. However I cannot port forward or open port or host a small web server through my home network.

Is there any better option available for me to open port and do my study work?

Surfing the net i found a VPS can be used. I signed up for free tier amazon AWS and dont know how to proceed from here. I need help because i'm tired with my ISP and useless IPV4.

Comment: Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You can do one of 3 things:

### 1) Use a full VPN

- Costs more, but is simple to use
- You do not need to manage the remote server at all
- Most providers focus on normal web browsing, so most do not support port forwarding

### 2) Setup a VPN from a VPS

- Costs less
- Requires you to manage your server, and keep the VPN server running
- [OpenVPN AS](https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/download-openvpn-as-sw.html) simplifies setting up an OpenVPN server

### 3) Use a service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

- Best if you only want to access a few ports externally
- Easiest option for a few ports
- Free option changes the hostname each time you connect

I tend to go for option 3, as it is easiest, but whichever you prefer to use is your choice

Comment: thanks and i am going to try it out.. option 3 . ii use option 3 because i need this thing for only a week.. and one more question.. ISP uses CGN was told to me by my friend.. how to findout  and clarify myself  that my ISP is using CGN.. please help

Comment: No problem, I use the free one a fair bit when I just want make demos available from networks I do not control.

Comment: Full disclosure, I am **not** affiliated with ngrok, I just think the tool is good, although if they want to send free stuff my way I would not say no to freebies :p